# How does one map just once all items of several of an object's direct child-arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping

I create an array of array of object and I would like to find out a way to map into it.
This is the array I have and want to map into just to return the name and the description:

```
const frenchList = {
  u: [{
    id: 1,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Uranophobie',
    description: 'Peur des cieux.',
  }, {
    id: 2,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Urinophobie',
  }],
  v: [{
    id: 3,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Vermiphobie',
    description: 'Peur des vers.',
  }],
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: The OP actually presents an object with properties with each property having assigned a sole array of object items **and not ...** _**"...  an array of array of object ..."**_

Comment: Sorry for the title mistake. just update it as @Andreas did mention. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The OP actually presents an object with properties with each *property* having assigned as its *value* an array of object items **and not ...** ***"...  an array of array of object ..."***.

Being aware of the structure one could choose an approach like the following one which [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)tens all of the processed object's [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and finally does [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each sub-structure item by [a new object which just features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) the latter [item's `name` and `description`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) ...

```js
const frenchList = {
  u: [{
    id: 1,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Uranophobie',
    description: 'Peur des cieux.',
  }, {
    id: 2,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Urinophobie',
  }],
  v: [{
    id: 3,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Vermiphobie',
    description: 'Peur des vers.',
  }],
};

console.log(
  'flattened values mapped as key value specific items ...',
  Object
    .values(frenchList)
    .flat()
    .map(({ name, description = '' }) => ({ name, description }))
  //.map(({ name, description = null }) => ({ name, description }))
);
console.log(
  'flattened values concatenated to string type items ...',
  Object
    .values(frenchList)
    .flat()
    .map(({ name, description = '###' }) => `${ name }: ${ description }`)
  //.map(({ name, description = '###' }) => [name, description].join(': '))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @fyardlest ... In case the OP might have not noticed yet, according to the OP's own answer and the there demonstrated requirement changes I slightly adapted the above logging example by providing a 2nd alternative which does concatenate `name` and `description`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys and thank you for the response. @Andreas I do listen to your advice and I have tried so far to solve this on my own, and learn about **Object.keys, Object.values and Object.entries** for the first time. So think you for that! Now it is time to learn about .flat() method from @Peter Seliger!

```js
const frenchList = {
  u: [{
    id: 1,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Uranophobie',
    description: 'Peur des cieux.',
  }, {
    id: 2,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Urinophobie',
  }],
  v: [{
    id: 3,
    rating: 5,
    name: 'Vermiphobie',
    description: 'Peur des vers.',
  }],
};

const myList = Object.entries(frenchList).map(([key, value]) =>
  value.map(val => `${val.name}: ${val.description}`)
)
console.log(myList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

I return what I exactly want in my React application (val.name & val.description). Thanks again guys!

Comment: I made your own solution an executable snippet which clearly shows the result being not just a single list of string items but a nested list of the latter. Thus in order to get returned an array of concatenated name and description values the above approach has to use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of `map` for the outer iteration.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a new const and make map with return only with attributes that necessary.

```
const newfrenchList = {
  u: frenchList.u.map(f => {
        const nFresh = {
            name: f.name,
            description: f.description
        };
        return nFresh;
   })
}
```